# Dynamically naming classes in aspx

Tags: asp.net, html

My goal is to create a series of clickable buttons that each have a unique image. Currently these image are stored as classes in CSS and this shows up fine - and I can call them by GImg EGCImg1, GImg EGCImg2... Etc. However, I want to make this dynamic so I can set X number of buttons instead of copy/pasting the code (which I hate to do). Below are the only 'useful' resources I was able to find, but unfortunately their suggestions didn't work for me.

http://forums.asp.net/t/1619813.aspx/1

http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/14033/Dynamic-CSS-Styling-in-ASP-NET-A-Flexible-Approach

So basically the below code, when I manually set the {0} will work perfectly. They'll even properly list along if I set this value - just all with the same image.

Only <% string.Format("GImg EGCImg{0}", i); %> is broken.

```
<% for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++){ %>
  <li>
     <label class="baseTemplate">
        <b>
           <%=Html.RadioButtonFor(x => x.Input.MailTemplate, i)%>
        </b><span class="<% string.Format("GImg EGCImg{0}", i); %>"><span class="CheckMark"/>
            </span>
      </label>
   </li><% } %>
```

Any and all suggestions are welcome,
Thanks!

Comment: "Only `<% string.Format("GImg EGCImg{0}", i); %>` is broken." – broken how?

Comment: Try `<%= string.Format(...) %>`

Comment: Don't you need a Response.Write to print your formated string?

Comment: Broken as in - it doesn't return anything. If I replace it with "GImg EGCImg1" it works perfectly - from what I can see it should return the same thing.

Comment: Oops, didn't realize I couldn't hit enter. Millimoose, I tried to use <%= and it tells me 'Expression Expected" and crashes the page. @Naner - I don't know what you mean

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're missing the `=` after `<%`

Also, you can do the following:

```
<span class="GImg EGCImg<%= i.ToString() %>"><span class="CheckMark"/></span>
```

Rather than using the String.Format method, just append the `i` at the end of your class. Little less overhead too.

The `=` is like saying `Response.Write`

Comment: As I said in a comment, <%= wouldn't work for me, neither would the other 3 variations, all saying "Expression Expected" But! Your second point worked! Thanks! I tried that before, but I didn't have the ToString(), makes sense.

Answer (score 1):

one option is to use inline css, so instead of class="classname", you would do style="background: red;". This is the easiest way without changing too much of your code. You can also generate dynamic css in the head, or link externally to a generated css file.

Comment: Can you give a small example please? I have an external css file - so I can use that, but I don't fully understand what you mean. Thanks!

Comment: 'Nevermind', since I got the answer from a different user - do feel free to answer it for others though :)

Comment: I think I misunderstood your question. I thought you were trying to avoid creating new css classes in your stylesheet every time you wanted to add a button. Glad you found the answer though =)

Answer (score 0):

You can use the Attributes.Add and Attributes.Remove

aspx file

```
<span id="YourContainer" runat="server">Report Type</span>
```

c# code behind

```
YourContainer.Attributes.Add("class", "active");
YourContainer.Attributes.Remove("class");
```